# Memory and time-efficient sorting of all rotations of a long array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, rotation, memory-efficient

I am looking for a memory and time-efficient solution to the below problem. It is easy to think of a basic algorithm that uses O(n<sup>2</sup>) memory and O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) time (?), and I would like to know if there is an algorithm that is significantly more memory and time-efficient (for certain input structures).

**Input**: Array a of length n populated with nonnegative integers. Each integer in the array is of magnitude less than or equal to b. I am interested in settings where n is large (tens of millions) and b is relatively small compared to n (hundreds). We can assume that the number of occurrences of any particular integer in a is bounded above by m, where m is on the order of n/b.

Consider the set of all rotations of the array a, i.e., if a = (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>), then its rotations are (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>), (a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>), (a<sub>3</sub>, a<sub>4</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>), ..., (a<sub>n</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n-1</sub>). Let r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>2</sub>, ..., r<sub>n</sub> denote the lexicographically sorted (increasing) ordering of the rotations of array a (using 0 < 1 < 2 < ... < b).

**Output**: Two arrays *first* and *last* that store the first and last elements of r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>2</sub>, ..., r<sub>n</sub> according to the sorted order.

**Basic algorithm** (not memory or time-efficient): Construct all rotations of a and store them in a matrix A (which uses O(n<sup>2</sup>) memory). Define a sorting routine (which uses a standard sorting technique) to sort A. Extract the first and last columns of the sorted matrix. Presumably the best time complexity of the sorting step is O(n<sup>2</sup> log n), i.e., O(n log n) for the sorting algorithm multiplied by O(n) for each pairwise comparison.

**Second algorithm**: We can walk through the array and store the positions in it that start with any integer i less than or equal to b (this is an O(n) time and O(nm) memory operation). Then, we can generate all rotations starting with a particular integer i and sort this matrix of rotations as per the basic algorithm (storing this matrix uses O(nm) memory and sorting presumably takes O(mn log m) time). It is easy to construct the output by repeating the process for every integer i from 0 to b.

Is there an approach that is more memory-efficient that uses a tailored sorting strategy? I am hopeful because storing the output only needs O(n) memory.

Comment: I think your first algorithm is good, but you don't have to create the whole matrix. It should be enough to identify each rotation by its offset and tailor the comparison used in sorting. Alternatively, double up the array (1, 2, 3, ..., n, 1, 2, 3, ...) and sort slices / views into that array with a standard sorting algorithm.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for the suggestion. Is O(n^2 log n) the best I can do in time complexity then?

Comment: Why O(n² log n)? The sorting should be O(n log n). Creating the vector to sort and output are O(n). Additional memory is O(n).

Comment: @MOehm The number of sorting steps can be O(n log n) and each pairwise comparison is O(n), isn't it? Maybe pairwise comparison is practically faster

Comment: Ah, I see. But O(n) is the upper bound for the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate [suffix array](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-array.html) for given array in O(nlogn). Note that linked implementation sorts cyclic shifts (special char is used there for suffixes - you don't need it) - exactly what you need (but "sorts" without physical sorting)

Then extract initial array elements addressed by indices from suffix array  - this is needed list of starting elements (and ending elements are at previous indices).

`P[0]` contains position of the smallest cyclic shift, so `A[P[0]]` and `A[P[0]-1]`  is the first pair, `P[1]` - position of the next smallest shift and so on

Answer (score 0):

Let's construct a better algorithm to find the first rotation.  Constructing the last in lexicographic order is the same problem, but sorting in reverse.  All that we need to track is what the minimum rotation is, and what positions we might be currently at.  Here is Python for that idea.

```
def min_rotation (elements):
    rotation = []
    positions = [i for i in range(len(elements))]
    while len(rotation) < len(elements):
        min_element = elements[positions[0]]
        new_positions = []
        for i in range(len(positions)):
            # Get the position and start rotating.
            position = positions[i]
            if elements[position] < min_element:
                min_element = elements[position]
            elif min_element <elements[position]:
                continue
            new_position = (position + 1) % len(elements)
            new_positions.append(new_position)
        positions = new_positions
        rotation.append(min_element)
    return rotation
```

The worst case scenario is `O(n)` memory and `O(n*n)` run time.  You will hit that on a constant array.

The expected case will be `O(n)` run time because the number of `positions` quickly moves towards 1.